# TreeView ScrollBar bug

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview in the winform application....

I added a node to it and reduced the width of the treeview such that the horizontal scroll
comes...

then i deleted the added node.

When i increase the treeview width the scroll comes...

But the scroll should not come..

What is the solution for this condition?

Comment: Try simplifing and presenting some code sample to us. Also a screen shot will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a threading issue. Does your code contain any `Application.DoEvents()`? Do you update the TreeView from the GUI thread? Please show some code.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   this.treeView1.Nodes.Add("dsfhfhfdshfhfshfshfdsabc");
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Remove();
  }

Comment: and the treeview is in one panel of the splitter and buttons are n another panel of splitter...and the splitter is movable horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-standard 3rd party treeview. The default one has bugs far worse than this.